# Why I got unable to get local issuer certificate for https://registry.yarnpkg.com

Tags: node.js, ssl, npm, yarnpkg

I just happen to get error `unable to get local issuer certificate` when running `yarn add <anything>`.

Yesterday it worked fine, but today it happens out of nowhere, I can't remember doing anything specifically.

After running `yarn config set strict-ssl false` it becomes working again, but that is very suspicious.

I know my question seems duplicate, but it doesn't. I have been searching everywhere but they seems to be for some cases such as running behind a corporate proxy or doing a new server set up. I am not behind any proxy.

Could you please help me see where should I investigate further to know the real root cause.

I am on macOS Monterey 12.0.1

### Full Log

```
z:~/work/littlepawcraft/mawsay[main !?]$ yarn add html2canvas --verbose
yarn add v1.22.19
verbose 0.185927225 Checking for configuration file "/Users/z/work/littlepawcraft/mawsay/.npmrc".
verbose 0.186249071 Checking for configuration file "/Users/z/.npmrc".
verbose 0.186511794 Found configuration file "/Users/z/.npmrc".
verbose 0.187669087 Checking for configuration file "/usr/local/etc/npmrc".
verbose 0.188048555 Checking for configuration file "/Users/z/work/littlepawcraft/mawsay/.npmrc".
verbose 0.188284222 Checking for configuration file "/Users/z/work/littlepawcraft/.npmrc".
verbose 0.188639829 Checking for configuration file "/Users/z/work/.npmrc".
verbose 0.188928153 Checking for configuration file "/Users/z/.npmrc".
verbose 0.189152548 Found configuration file "/Users/z/.npmrc".
verbose 0.189640273 Checking for configuration file "/Users/.npmrc".
verbose 0.191425842 Checking for configuration file "/Users/z/work/littlepawcraft/mawsay/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.191663753 Checking for configuration file "/Users/z/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.191811016 Found configuration file "/Users/z/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.192157101 Checking for configuration file "/usr/local/etc/yarnrc".
verbose 0.192324062 Checking for configuration file "/Users/z/work/littlepawcraft/mawsay/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.192446487 Checking for configuration file "/Users/z/work/littlepawcraft/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.192626013 Checking for configuration file "/Users/z/work/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.192732424 Checking for configuration file "/Users/z/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.192809809 Found configuration file "/Users/z/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.192994673 Checking for configuration file "/Users/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.196011087 current time: 2022-06-29T01:58:26.170Z
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
verbose 0.464574716 Performing "GET" request to "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/html2canvas".
verbose 0.619253995 Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1530:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:944:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:725:12)
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/html2canvas: unable to get local issuer certificate".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/Users/z/work/littlepawcraft/mawsay/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check if your .npmrc does not specify manual CAs.
2. Check if you are behind a corporate proxy.
3. Check if your local certificates are corrupted.

Comment: Thanks, it turns out my `/Users/z/.npmrc` has a line with `ca[]=` in it. After removing that, everything become working again.

Comment: It was the corporate proxy for me Zscaler.

Comment: 4. `export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/path/to/file/with/extra_trusted_root_cas.pem`